# SAS IF then statement

Tags: sas

Hello for whatever reason my if then statement will not work for this code. What I am trying to get it to do is (kinda obvious but whatever) if the salary is LE 30,000 then make new variable income equal to low. Here is what I have so far.

```
data newdd2;
input subject group$ year salary : comma7. @@;
IF (salary <= 30,000) THEN income = 'low';
datalines;
1 A  2  53,900    2 B  2  37,400    3  A  1  49,500
4 C  2  43,900    5 B  3  38,400    6  A  3  39,500
7 A  3  53,600    8 B  2  37,700    9  C  1  49,900
10 C  2  43,300   11 B  3  57,400    12 B  3  39,500
13 B  1  33,900   14 A  2  41,400    15 C  2  49,500
16 C  1  43,900   17 B  1  39,400    18 A  3  39,900
19 A  2  53,600   20  A  2  37,700   21 C  3  42,900
22 C  2  43,300   23 B  1   57,400   24  C  3  69,500
25  C  2  33,900  26  A  2  35,300   27 A  2  47,500
28 C  2  43,900  29  B  3  38,400   30 A  1  32,500
31 A  3  53,600   32 B  2  37,700   33 C  1  41,600
34 C  2  43,300   35 B  3  57,400   36 B  3  39,500
37 B  2  33,900    38 A  2  41,400   39 C  2  79,500
40 C  1  43,900    41 C  1  29,500   42 A  3  39,900
43 A  2  53,600    44 A  2  37,500   45 C  3  42,900
46 C  2  43,300    47 B  1  47,400   48 C  3  59,500
 run;
```

The error I keep getting is (The work dataset may be incomplete), however I am sure that my code is correct I've tried a number of things but no success yet thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use a comma in a numeric literal.

```
IF (salary <= 30000) THEN income = 'low';
```